# Fiware Orion-ld Polygon Data Insert Error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

although the polygon data conforms to the standard structure, I get an error when I want to add it to the fiware side.

[image]

The polygons data we use is below;

I)

{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[36.2461465,37.0648871],[36.2460744,37.0648355],[36.2459429,37.0647120],[36.2459742,37.0646980],[36.2457908,37.0645057],[36.2459484,37.0644000],[36.2460785,37.0643124],[36.2461040,37.0642925],[36.2462077,37.0642114],[36.2463421,37.0640831],[36.2464975,37.0642173],[36.2463498,37.0640466],[36.2466107,37.0642657],[36.2469810,37.0644730],[36.2474060,37.0642997],[36.2469520,37.0645424],[36.2469766,37.0645626],[36.2479976,37.0640023],[36.2480284,37.0640110],[36.2482431,37.0642928],[36.2482517,37.0642868],[36.2483085,37.0642595],[36.2480964,37.0639710],[36.2481014,37.0639406],[36.2483925,37.0637744],[36.2486570,37.0636293],[36.2487646,37.0638604],[36.2487989,37.0639320],[36.2488132,37.0639655],[36.2488716,37.0640896],[36.2486873,37.0642026],[36.2486031,37.0642577],[36.2485100,37.0643203],[36.2484413,37.0644238],[36.2483143,37.0645177],[36.2481813,37.0646141],[36.2480689,37.0646989],[36.2479859,37.0647609],[36.2477950,37.0648680],[36.2476609,37.0649424],[36.2476550,37.0649478],[36.2477896,37.0651105],[36.2478810,37.0652241],[36.2479723,37.0653378],[36.2481314,37.0655357],[36.2479478,37.0656056],[36.2479601,37.0656207],[36.2478733,37.0656585],[36.2477440,37.0657095],[36.2476484,37.0655959],[36.2476649,37.0655859],[36.2475542,37.0654415],[36.2474549,37.0653053],[36.2473347,37.0651292],[36.2472768,37.0650530],[36.2472231,37.0650896],[36.2465866,37.0654223],[36.2461465,37.0648871]],[[36.2478183,37.0636569],[36.2478183,37.0636569],[36.2478365,37.0636470],[36.2478183,37.0636569]]]}

II)

[image]

{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[36.2453447,37.0638166],[36.2456068,37.0636280],[36.2457406,37.0635516],[36.2457631,37.0635874],[36.2461758,37.0633492],[36.2461813,37.0633044],[36.2462984,37.0632325],[36.2464379,37.0631695],[36.2467336,37.0630211],[36.2467560,37.0630524],[36.2470796,37.0628950],[36.2473921,37.0627600],[36.2477268,37.0625936],[36.2477325,37.0626071],[36.2478608,37.0625530],[36.2479334,37.0625395],[36.2479896,37.0626289],[36.2481179,37.0625749],[36.2481066,37.0625212],[36.2481569,37.0625211],[36.2482128,37.0625389],[36.2482465,37.0625836],[36.2482578,37.0626328],[36.2482750,37.0627671],[36.2483202,37.0629193],[36.2480245,37.0630498],[36.2475949,37.0632746],[36.2474387,37.0633376],[36.2472769,37.0634230],[36.2471207,37.0634995],[36.2468808,37.0636164],[36.2465963,37.0637827],[36.2463175,37.0639534],[36.2462952,37.0639848],[36.2461662,37.0638239],[36.2459464,37.0640333],[36.2459597,37.0639049],[36.2461662,37.0638239],[36.2462952,37.0639848],[36.2461728,37.0641329],[36.2459387,37.0643170],[36.2457045,37.0644607],[36.2456315,37.0643713],[36.2455532,37.0642045],[36.2454234,37.0639508],[36.2453447,37.0638166]]]}

Error;

[image]

Edit:

**I solved the problem but I couldn't update here for a while. If there are overlapping lines or drawings such as dots in the Polygon data, it does not allow to add fiware.**

Answer (score 0):

Polygons are supported as part of the `location` attribute (or indeed any `type=GeoProperty`. I'm not sure what your error is - the following request is working fine for me using the [Orion-LD](https://github.com/Fiware/context.Orion-LD) context broker - the version is **1.1.0** - maybe your NGSI request is incorrectly formatted.

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Link: <http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:001",
    "type": "TemperatureSensor",
    "category": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "sensor"
    },
    "temperature": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": 25,
        "unitCode": "CEL"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    36.2461465,
                    37.0648871
                ],
                [
                    36.2460744,
                    37.0648355
                ],
                [
                    36.2459429,
                    37.064712
                ],
                [
                    36.2459742,
                    37.064698
                ],
                [
                    36.2457908,
                    37.0645057
                ],
                [
                    36.2459484,
                    37.0644
                ],
                [
                    36.2460785,
                    37.0643124
                ],
                [
                    36.246104,
                    37.0642925
                ],
                [
                    36.2462077,
                    37.0642114
                ],
                [
                    36.2463421,
                    37.0640831
                ],
                [
                    36.2464975,
                    37.0642173
                ],
                [
                    36.2463498,
                    37.0640466
                ],
                [
                    36.2466107,
                    37.0642657
                ],
                [
                    36.246981,
                    37.064473
                ],
                [
                    36.247406,
                    37.0642997
                ],
                [
                    36.246952,
                    37.0645424
                ],
                [
                    36.2469766,
                    37.0645626
                ],
                [
                    36.2479976,
                    37.0640023
                ],
                [
                    36.2480284,
                    37.064011
                ],
                [
                    36.2482431,
                    37.0642928
                ],
                [
                    36.2482517,
                    37.0642868
                ],
                [
                    36.2483085,
                    37.0642595
                ],
                [
                    36.2480964,
                    37.063971
                ],
                [
                    36.2481014,
                    37.0639406
                ],
                [
                    36.2483925,
                    37.0637744
                ],
                [
                    36.248657,
                    37.0636293
                ],
                [
                    36.2487646,
                    37.0638604
                ],
                [
                    36.2487989,
                    37.063932
                ],
                [
                    36.2488132,
                    37.0639655
                ],
                [
                    36.2488716,
                    37.0640896
                ],
                [
                    36.2486873,
                    37.0642026
                ],
                [
                    36.2486031,
                    37.0642577
                ],
                [
                    36.24851,
                    37.0643203
                ],
                [
                    36.2484413,
                    37.0644238
                ],
                [
                    36.2483143,
                    37.0645177
                ],
                [
                    36.2481813,
                    37.0646141
                ],
                [
                    36.2480689,
                    37.0646989
                ],
                [
                    36.2479859,
                    37.0647609
                ],
                [
                    36.247795,
                    37.064868
                ],
                [
                    36.2476609,
                    37.0649424
                ],
                [
                    36.247655,
                    37.0649478
                ],
                [
                    36.2477896,
                    37.0651105
                ],
                [
                    36.247881,
                    37.0652241
                ],
                [
                    36.2479723,
                    37.0653378
                ],
                [
                    36.2481314,
                    37.0655357
                ],
                [
                    36.2479478,
                    37.0656056
                ],
                [
                    36.2479601,
                    37.0656207
                ],
                [
                    36.2478733,
                    37.0656585
                ],
                [
                    36.247744,
                    37.0657095
                ],
                [
                    36.2476484,
                    37.0655959
                ],
                [
                    36.2476649,
                    37.0655859
                ],
                [
                    36.2475542,
                    37.0654415
                ],
                [
                    36.2474549,
                    37.0653053
                ],
                [
                    36.2473347,
                    37.0651292
                ],
                [
                    36.2472768,
                    37.065053
                ],
                [
                    36.2472231,
                    37.0650896
                ],
                [
                    36.2465866,
                    37.0654223
                ],
                [
                    36.2461465,
                    37.0648871
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}'
```

Comment: Clarifications: "location" is the "preferred" name of a GeoProperty,. but any name can be used. Also notice that Jason's example is using key-values (or "Concise" format"). In the default "normalized format, the payload body would look different: "geo-prop" { "type": "GeoProperty", "value"; { "type": "Polygon", "value": [ ... ] }}. (of the three "FIWARE NGSI-LD brokers", only Orion-LD supports the Concise format right now)

The error seems to be that the first point and the last point in the polygon don't coincide, and they must.

Answer (score 0):

Found another problem in the coordinates: *[36.2461465,37.0648871]],[[36.2478183,37.0636569]*.    One array of points is ended and another array is started ...   If you change the "]],[[" for "],[", that part should be OK.   But, you still need to finish the polygon with the same point as the very first point of the polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We removed second array Its worked but we have another polygon data without second data. Since the polygon data is long, I could not add it here. I wrote it in the topic title, may you check it out?